# No se puede enviar info a una acción para actualizar estado de redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tengo una función que se llama fetchuser esta recibe un parametro user y dee ste saco el token del usuario que inició sesión, y lo envio a una función llamada getUserData, y obtengo toda la información del usuario en la variable data

El problema es que no puedo enviarle la información a la acción, si uso  return async (dispatch) para enviar la info con el dispatch, no hace nada, no envia datos, ni el console mustra nada como es una promesa, no se si se puede enviar así como lo hice, no muestra error ni nada pero tampoco actualiza el estado.

Lo que quiero hacer es enviar esa información a la acción fetchUserSuccess y de ahí al reducer para actuaizar el estado global con redux

Gracias por la ayuda

actions/userActions

```
    const fetchUserSuccess = (user) => ({
      type: GET_USER,
      payload: user,
    });
    
    
    export const fetchUser = (user) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {
    const {data} = await getUserData(user.token);
    if(!data){
    console.log("no existe data para este usuario")
    }else{
      console.log(data);
       dispatch(fetchUserSuccess(data[0]));
  }
}
```

}

//Reducer

```
import { LOGIN, ERROR_MESSAGE, LOGOUT, GET_USER } from "../actions/userActions";

const initState = {
  user: {},
};

const userReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
 
  if (action.type === GET_USER) {
    return {
      ...state,
      user: { ...state.user, ...action.payload },
    }
  }

  return state;
};

export default userReducer;
```

Index

```
import "react-app-polyfill/ie11";
import "react-app-polyfill/stable";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProducts } from "./redux/actions/productActions";
import { fetchBanners } from './redux/actions/bannerActions';
import App from "./App";
import "./assets/scss/style.scss";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import store from "./redux/store/store"


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";
import { save, load } from "redux-localstorage-simple";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/rootReducer";


const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    load(),
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware( thunk, promise, save()))
  );

export default store
```

RootReducer.js

```
import currencyReducer from "./currencyReducer";
import productReducer from "./productReducer";
import cartReducer from "./cartReducer";
import wishlistReducer from "./wishlistReducer";
import compareReducer from "./compareReducer";
import bannerReducer from "./bannerReducer"
import userReducer from "./userReducer"
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { createMultilanguageReducer } from "redux-multilanguage";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  multilanguage: createMultilanguageReducer({ currentLanguageCode: "en" }),
  currencyData: currencyReducer,
  productData: productReducer,
  bannerData: bannerReducer,
  cartData: cartReducer,
  wishlistData: wishlistReducer,
  compareData: compareReducer,
  userData: userReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Componente que usa la funcion fetchUser()

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, {
  Fragment,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
} from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MetaTags from "react-meta-tags";
import { BreadcrumbsItem } from "react-breadcrumbs-dynamic";
import Tab from "react-bootstrap/Tab";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import LayoutThree from "../../layouts/LayoutThree";
import Breadcrumb from "../../wrappers/breadcrumb/Breadcrumb";
import { getSectors } from "../../utils/services/storeServices";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { definitions } from "../../utils/definitions";
import {
  fetchUser,
  login,
  register,
  clearError,
} from "../../redux/actions/userActions";



const LoginRegister = ({
  location,
  login,
  register,
  fetchUser,
  user,
  clearError,
}) => {
  const [neighborhoods, setNeighborhoods] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();
  const { pathname } = location;

  const {
    register: loginForm,
    handleSubmit: handleLoginSubmit,
    formState: { errors: loginErrors },
    reset: loginReset,
  } = useForm();

  const {
    register: registerForm,
    handleSubmit: handleRegisterSubmit,
    watch: watchRegisterForm,
    formState: { errors: registerErrors },
    reset: registerReset,
  } = useForm();

  const city = watchRegisterForm("city");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user?.token) {
      fetchUser(user);
      return history.push("/");
    }
    if (user.errorMessage) {
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Error!",
        text: user.errorMessage,
        icon: "error",
        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
      }).then(function () {
        loginReset();
        registerReset()
        clearError();
      });
    }
  }, [user, history, loginReset, registerReset, clearError, fetchUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getNeighborhoods();
  }, []);

  const getNeighborhoods = async () => {
    const { data } = await getSectors();
    if (!!data) {
      setNeighborhoods(data);
    }
  };

  const barrios = useMemo(() => {
    let hoods = [];
    if (neighborhoods.length > 0) {
      hoods = city
        ? neighborhoods
            .filter((n) => n.city === city)
            .map(({ _id, name }) => ({ value: _id, label: name }))
        : [{ value: "NON", label: "No se ha seleccionado Ciudad" }];
    }
    return hoods;
  }, [city, neighborhoods]);

  const handleRegisterUser = async (form) => {
    let clientInfo = {
      password: form.password,
      docId: form.docId,
      docType: form.docType,
      email: form.email,
      firstName: form.firstName,
      lastName: form.lastName,
      phone: form.phone,
      role: "shopper",
      roleData: {
        addresses: [
          {
            addressId: Date.now().toString(),
            address: form.address,
            alias: form.alias,
            city: form.city,
          },
        ],
        billingAccounts: [],
        image: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/14.jpg",
        shopperIn: ["5f24b33d376b2705690ef855"],
        storeId: "5f24b33d376b2705690ef855",
        userId: "",
      },
    };
    await register(clientInfo);
    return      
  };

  const handleLoginUser = async (data) => {
    await login(data);
    return;
  };


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MetaTags>
        <title>Estori | Login</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Compare page of flone react minimalist eCommerce template."
        />
      </MetaTags>
      <BreadcrumbsItem to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>
        Inicio
      </BreadcrumbsItem>
      <BreadcrumbsItem to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + pathname}>
        Autenticación
      </BreadcrumbsItem>
      <LayoutThree>
        {/* breadcrumb */}
        <Breadcrumb />
        <div className="login-register-area pt-100 pb-100">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-7 col-md-12 ml-auto mr-auto">
                <div className="login-register-wrapper">
                  <Tab.Container defaultActiveKey="login">
                    <Nav variant="pills" className="login-register-tab-list">
                      <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey="login">
                          <h4>Iniciar Sesión</h4>
                        </Nav.Link>
                      </Nav.Item>
                      <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey="register">
                          <h4>Registrarse</h4>
                        </Nav.Link>
                      </Nav.Item>
                    </Nav>
                    <Tab.Content>
                      <Tab.Pane eventKey="login">
                        <div className="login-form-container">
                          <div className="login-register-form">
                            <form onSubmit={handleLoginSubmit(handleLoginUser)}>
                              <label>Correo</label>
                              <ErrorMessage
                                errors={loginErrors}
                                name="email"
                                as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                              />
                              <input
                                type="email"
                                {...loginForm("email", {
                                  required:
                                    "Debe ingresar un correo electrónico",
                                  pattern: {
                                    value: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
                                    message:
                                      "El valor ingresado no corresponde a un formato de email valido",
                                  },
                                })}
                              />
                              <label>Contraseña</label>
                              <ErrorMessage
                                errors={loginErrors}
                                name="password"
                                as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                              />
                              <input
                                {...loginForm("password", {
                                  required: "Debe ingresar su contraseña",
                                })}
                                type="password"
                              />

                              <div className="button-box">
                                <div className="login-toggle-btn">
                                  <input type="checkbox" />
                                  <label className="ml-10">Remember me</label>
                                  <Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}>
                                    Forgot Password?
                                  </Link>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit">
                                  <span>Login</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Tab.Pane>
                      <Tab.Pane eventKey="register">
                        <div className="login-form-container">
                          <div className="login-register-form">
                            <div className="global-content">
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-12">
                                  <label>Correo *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="email"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    id="emailRegister"
                                    type="email"
                                    {...registerForm("email", {
                                      required:"Debe ingresar un correo electrónico",
                                      pattern: {
                                        value: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
                                        message:
                                          "El valor ingresado no corresponde a un formato de email valido",
                                      },
                                    })}
                                  />
                                  <label>Contraseña *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="password"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    type="password"
                                    {...registerForm("password", {
                                      required: "Debe ingresar una contraseña",
                                    })}
                                  />
                                  <label>Confirmar Contraseña *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="confirmPassword"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    type="password"
                                    {...registerForm("confirmPassword", {
                                      required: "Confirma tu contraseña",
                                      validate: (value) =>
                                        value ===
                                          watchRegisterForm("password") ||
                                        "Las contraseñas no coinciden",
                                    })}
                                  />
                                  <label>Nombre *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="firstName"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    type="text"
                                    {...registerForm("firstName", {
                                      required: "Ingrese su nombre",
                                    })}
                                  />
                                  <label>Apellido *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="lastName"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    type="text"
                                    {...registerForm("lastName", {
                                      required: "Ingrese su apellido",
                                    })}
                                  />
                                  <label>Celular *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="phone"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    type="text"
                                    {...registerForm("phone", {
                                      required: "Ingrese su numero de contacto",
                                      pattern: {
                                        value:
                                          /^(57)?[3]{1}[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$/,
                                        message:
                                          "El numero de telefono no posee el formato de un numero de Colombia (ejemplo: 573041111111)",
                                      },
                                    })}
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                  <label>Documento *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="docType"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <select
                                    {...registerForm("docType", {
                                      required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
                                    })}
                                    size="default"
                                  >
                                    {definitions.ID.TYPES.map((doc) => (
                                      <option value={doc.value}>
                                        {doc.display}
                                      </option>
                                    ))}
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-9">
                                  <label>No. de Documento *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="docId"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    {...registerForm("docId", {
                                      required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
                                    })}
                                  />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-12">
                                  <label>Ciudad *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="city"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <select
                                    {...registerForm("city", {
                                      required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
                                    })}
                                  >
                                    {definitions.STORES.CITIES.map((city) => (
                                      <option value={city.value}>
                                        {city.display}
                                      </option>
                                    ))}
                                  </select>
                                  <label>Barrio *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="neighborhood"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <select
                                    {...registerForm("neighborhood", {
                                      required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
                                    })}
                                  >
                                    {barrios.map((opt) => (
                                      <option
                                        value={opt.value}
                                        key={`option-${opt.value}`}
                                      >
                                        {opt.label}
                                      </option>
                                    ))}
                                  </select>
                                  <label>Dirección *</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="address"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    {...registerForm("address", {
                                      required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
                                    })}
                                  />
                                  <label>Alias</label>
                                  <ErrorMessage
                                    errors={registerErrors}
                                    name="alias"
                                    as={<p className="text-danger" />}
                                  />
                                  <input
                                    {...registerForm("alias", {
                                      required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
                                    })}
                                    placeholder="Ej: Mi Casa"
                                  />

                                  {/* <Checkbox {...registerForm("termsAccept", "C")}>
                                    <span className="text-muted">
                                      <small>
                                        {" "}
                                        Acepto la{" "}
                                        <a
                                          href="https://estori.co/politica-de-privacidad"
                                          className="text-muted font-weight-bold"
                                          target="blank"
                                        >
                                          política de seguridad
                                        </a>{" "}
                                        y los{" "}
                                        <a
                                          href="https://estori.co/politica-de-privacidad"
                                          className="text-muted font-weight-bold"
                                          target="blank"
                                        >
                                          términos y condiciones
                                        </a>{" "}
                                        del servicio de Mercabot
                                      </small>
                                    </span>
                                  </Checkbox> */}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <button
                                  className="btn btn-color3 w-50"
                                  onClick={handleRegisterSubmit(
                                    handleRegisterUser
                                  )}
                                >
                                  Siguiente
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Tab.Pane>
                    </Tab.Content>
                  </Tab.Container>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </LayoutThree>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

LoginRegister.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.object,
  user: PropTypes.object,
  login: PropTypes.func,
  register: PropTypes.func,
  fetchUser: PropTypes.func,
  clearError: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    user: state.userData.user,
  }
};



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (user) => {
      dispatch(login(user));
    },
    fetchUser: (user) => {
      (fetchUser(user));
    },
    
    clearError: () => {
      dispatch(clearError());
    },
    register: (user) => {
      dispatch(register(user))
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginRegister);
```

Comment: Como ya estás usando "async/await" no es necesario que uses el then. "x" ya es valor devuelvo por la promesa, no la promesa en sí. Por otro lado, dónde está la función fetchUser? En un component?

Comment: Hola, si fetchUser viene de un componente, trae info del usuario que inicio sesión y el token, dejé de usar then y obtuve la información del usuario, pero igual no logro que pase a fetchUserSuccess

Comment: Dónde estás inicializando tu `store`? Es una parte fundamental para que funcione redux, sería bueno pusieras el código relevante en la pregunta

Comment: Hola, si, en el index está el store

Comment: ya veo... lo que aún tampoco me queda claro es cómo llamas a tu acción  `fetchUser` desde tu componente, pues el `dispatch` de algún lado viene

Comment: lo acabo de agregar, pero el componente si envía la info correctamente

Comment: en tu `mapDispatchToProps` tienes `(fetchUser(user))` y no `dispatch(fetchUser(user))`, si no es eso entonces tendré que darle una vueltita mas

Comment: Si parece que si era eso, ya pude actualizar el estado y sacar la info que requería para mostrar al usuario, Muchas Gracias